# Tuning long running query

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica

```
SELECT a AS a,
   b AS b,
   c AS c,
   d AS d,
   e AS e,
   f AS f,
   g AS g,
   h AS h
FROM ( 
   SELECT P.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p.a, RANK_NM 
      ORDER BY P.ID DESC) RW_NUM 
   FROM ( 
      SELECT T.a,
         T.b,
         T.c,
         T.d,
         T.e,
         T.f,
         T.g,
         T.h,
         T.ID
         DENSE_RANK() over (PARTITION BY T.a 
         ORDER BY T.b, T.c, T.d
         , T.e, T.f, T.g, T.h
         DESC) RANK_NM 
      FROM TEST_TABLE T ) p) Y 
WHERE RW_NUM = 1
```

I got this query for tuning from production team, I dont have access to production and other things, I have to give query to production guys to execute and they are expecting a miracle. Problem is TEST_TABLE contains 98 million records and this query is used in informatica and creating a huge cache. Is there any way query can be written in better way, just at looking at query. I know lot of things require and information is needed for tuning but this is all I got. :) Database is oracle 10 g.

Comment: What where clause uses the SQ in Informatica?

Comment: this query is used in informatica in sql override

Answer (score 0):

As Podiluska says, optimizing a query without being able to see the query plan, or add indices is a bit mental.

However, it does appear that there is some redundant "order by" action going on: the very inner query has:

```
ORDER BY T.b, T.c, T.d
         , T.e, T.f, T.g, T.h
         DESC)
```

and the query outside that has:

```
ORDER BY P.ID DESC
```

It's possible that the query optimizer is ignoring the inner order by, but you might get some improvement if you can remove that order by statement, especially if there is no index that matches.

Comment: The inner order by is being used in the DENSE_RANK window function so the query optimizer cannot ignore it. It's needed to calculate the RANK_NM value that is then  used in the outer ROW_NUMBER window function.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have hidden other fields, what this query is really doing is a

```
SELECT DISTINCT a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h FROM TEST_TABLE
```

If there are more fields, the inner analytic function is redundant, as Neville pointed. You could rewrite it like this:

```
SELECT
  a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, extra1, extra2
FROM
(
  SELECT
    a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, extra1, extra2,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h ORDER BY ID DESC) RW_NUM
  FROM TEST_TABLE
)
WHERE RW_NUM = 1
```